# Enviar un campo diferente al ID para editar un formulario

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy empezando a programar una aplicación web con php y mysql, pero he tropezado con un problema.
Resulta que tengo una tabla que muestra una serie de campos y valores de una tabla. He añadido un botón para visualizar, editar o eliminar una fila de la tabla. 
Para ello, utilizo el "id" de la tabla

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";    
$user_id=null;
$sql1= "select * from batchinput where batchactive like 'Yes'";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
?>
```

Se muestran los datos, y al final de cada fila he puesto los botones, utilizando el id. Por ejemplo, para el botón editar:

```
<a href="./formulario.php?id=<?php echo $r["id"];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Edit</a>
```

En la página formulario se abre el formulario, recogiendo los datos que haya en la base de datos, y así poder editar los campos:

```
<?php
include "conexion.php";

$user_id=null;
$sql1= "select * from batchinput where id = ".$_GET["id"];
$query = $con->query($sql1);
$batchinput = null;
if($query->num_rows>0){
while ($r=$query->fetch_object()){
  $batchinput=$r;
  break;
}

  }
?>
```

etc...

Pues bien, ahora he pensado que en vez de recoger el id, quiero seleccionar la fila en la base de datos utilizando el campo batchnumber. Pues donde he puesto "id" lo cambio por "batchnumber", o eso pensaba, pero me da "connection error", y no lo muestra.

La razón por la que quiero hacer esto, es que tengo una segunda tabla en la que añado comentarios a cada batch, por lo que se van generando IDs diferentes a la tabla principal, pero el batchnumber se mantiene, de modo que al enviar desde la tabla el enlace con el número de batch, se abriría el formulario para editar los campos de la segunda tabla.

Pero no me funciona.
¿Qué he pasado por alto?

¡Gracias y un saludo!
Alex.

Comment: Si tu campo **batchnumber** es unique no debería haber problema. Igualmente es posible que el problema venga por qué tu id es numérico y el batchnumber texto y debes envolverlo entre comillas. Igualmente cuidado con esas consultas tal y como las haces te expones a INYECCIÓN SQL.

Comment: Efectivamente, eran las comillas... ¡vaya despiste! La solución siempre está en el código ;-P Muy amable por tu ayuda e indicaciones, @Xerif. Soy nuevo en la programación, así que comencé con scripts sencillos para comprender un poco mejor las bases e ir subiendo en complejidad. Quizás no es el mejor procedimiento, pero el contenido no es muy complejo y me ayuda a avanzar, antes de entrar con PDO y niveles más avanzados.

Answer (score 1):

Mencionas que el error es de conexión. Si tu error fuera por el campo entonces tendrías un error o un warnning y te diría el problema de la consulta.

Intenta estar seguro de que cierras las conexiones y las vuelves a abrir antes de hacer una consulta, es un error muy común cuando se trabaja así. Pienso que en algún punto cierras tu conexión y luego intentas hacer una consulta. También puede ser que la abras y nunca la cierres y tu sesión caduque.

Saludos, espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: Hola. esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta. Cuando tengas 50 de reputación podrás comentar. Mientras tanto por favor trata de escribir respuestas que no requieran aclaraciones del autor.

Comment: Gracias, Iván. No era la solución al problema, pero me ha hecho pensar. Tengo que abrir y cerrar adecuadamente las conexiones, porque creo que podría estar causándome problemas con otros scripts.